# Generic Method to Pass class as a parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am new here so please before marking my question -1 please provides your suggestion.

In my below code I want to create a generic type function instead of "SendFirstRequest" and "SendSecondRequest". OR How can do we pass and cast object?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MyFirstRequest objRequest1 = new MyFirstRequest
                {
                    MyFirstRequest_ID = 1
                };
                SendFirstRequest(objRequest1);

                MySecondRequest objRequest2 = new MySecondRequest
                {
                    MySecondRequest_ID = 1
                };
                SendSecondRequest(objRequest2);
            }

            public static MyFirstResponse SendFirstRequest(MyFirstRequest objRequest)
            {
                MyFirstResponse objResponse = CreateDate1(objRequest);
                return objResponse;
            }

            public static MySecondResponse SendSecondRequest(MySecondRequest objRequest)
            {
                MySecondResponse objResponse = CreateDate2(objRequest);
                return objResponse;
            }

            public static MyFirstResponse CreateDate1(MyFirstRequest request)
            {
                MyFirstResponse objRespo = new MyFirstResponse
                {
                    MyFirstResponse_Name = "A",
                    MyFirstResponse_Address = "Address1"
                };
                return objRespo;
            }


    public static MySecondResponse CreateDate2(MySecondRequest request)
    {
        MySecondResponse objRespo = new MySecondResponse
            {
                MySecondResponse_Name = "A",
                MySecondResponse_Address = "Address1"
            };
        return objRespo;
    }
```

Comment: [Use inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: My question is for object or generic type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no apparent relationship between `MyFirstRequest`, `MyFirstResponse`, `MySecondRequest` and `MySecondResponse` to use generics effectively.  The types even have different property names because they're prefixed by the class name (which would prevent the use of `dynamic` as well).

This does not seem to be a good candidate for generics.  Reflection would reduce code if you have more than just these two types, but would defer errors to runtime.

Some design changes that would make generics more plausible:

- Take the class name prefixes off of the `Response` classes' properties
- Use a base class or interface to define the (now) common properties of `MyFirstResponse` and `MySecondResponse`
- Add a `CreateRequest` method to each `Request` type that will return the appropriate `Response` type.